# With cluse in insert

Tags: oracle, plsql

Odd things going on with procedure below.

When I run procedure it insert into table only 125 records. When I insert data without procedure with the same parameters it gives me 15000 records. Do you have any ideas what could it be?

```
create or replace procedure calc_p(p_startdate number,
                                   p_end_date  number,
                                   p_id        number) is

begin

  dbms_output.put_line('Start: ' || substr(localtimestamp, 1, 17));

  delete rep_pd
   where b_id = p_id
     and rep_date between p_startdate and p_end_date;

  -- commit;

  insert into rep_pd
    with cont
    (rep_date, b_id, con_number, okres_zap) as
     (select /*+ materialize*/
       rep_date,
       b_id,
       con_number,
       nvl(maturity_date - origin_date, 0) as okres_zap
        from con@sg_al
       where description not in ('OVER', 'Overn')
         and b_id = p_id
         and rep_date between p_startdate 
         and p_end_date)

    select mr.suffix1,
           mr.data_danych,
           ma.rep_date,
           b_id,
           mr.k_symbol,
           konto_nazwa,
           case
             when mr.k_nazwa likr '%EXT%' then
              '04'
             when mr.k_symbol like '3731%' then
              '12'
             else
              mr.typ_k_symbol
           end as cl_t,
           ma.okres_zap,
           mr.rezydent_symbol,
           mr.w_symbol as cu,
           mr.sal_ma_pl as outstanding,
           get_pd_account(k_symbol) AS depo substr(to_number(to_char(data_danych, 'yyyymmdd')), 7, 2) as dzien
      from abc.a_mr mr
      left join cont ma
        on ma.b_id = p_id
       and to_date(ma.rep_date, 'YY/MM/DD') = mr.data_danych
       and ma.con_number = mr.suffix1
     where sal_ma_pl <> 0
       and get_pd_account(k_symbol) is not null
       and nvl(typ_k_symbol, '20') not in ('01', '02', '02A')
       and mr.data_danych between to_date(p_startdate, 'YY/MM/DD') and
           to_date(p_end_date, 'YY/MM/DD');

  -- commit;

  dbms_output.put_line('Koniec: ' || substr(localtimestamp, 1, 17));

end calc_p;
```

Comment: The same INSERT, encapsulated into BEGIN-END (i.e. transformed into a stored procedure) should produce the same result. I don't see any reason why not so - maybe you're misinterpreting reality.

Comment: remove embedded commits within your procedure. Issue one commit at the very end within the application. Those maybe harmful for transaction integrity.

Comment: @Aleksander it's interesting that your start and end date parameters are numbers, but in your query, you expect them to have the format `yy/mm/dd`. That seems wrong. Also, why only two digit years? We didn't go through Y2K for 2-digit years to still be in use today (for anything other than reporting/generating filenames/etc, that is, and even then ... yuck!)

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors or unadvised uses in your code:

1. When I copy-paste your code in my editor, I see an error. There is `,` missing between your `depo` and `dzien` columns in `select`.

Before anything else, double check that you gave us a correct code and that you haven't erased one part of the code. Also, **double check that you haven't missed the same part of the code when transferring it in or out of the procedure.**

2. As Littlefoot stated in the comment to your question, there should be no difference between `INSERT` stetements inside and outside stored procedures, if they are just being encapsulated with `BEGIN END`. There is one difference however, and that is the way you're defining your input parameters.

I see that you are defining your `p_startdate` and `p_end_date` as `NUMBER` parameters. Possible difference is that you're really expecting dates. The difference between the results of your insert inside and outside the procedure can easily be due to defining your `p_startdate` and `p_end_date` parameters as numbers.

If after these corrections you still get a difference in results, please provide us with some sample table data that is getting you that difference.

Comment: Sorry for my typo with comma. `p_startdate` and `p_end_date` must be defined as `NUMBER`, because of indexes on table con@sg_al. Why I can't transform  `NUMBER` into `DATE` 'YY/MM/DD' ? It works when I try sth like this ->  ```SQL select to_date(20190930,'YY/MM/DD')
FROM DUAL; ```

Comment: @alexander you're right, I made a mistake: numbers can pass that format. You just have to be careful that those data values are precise. Is it possible for you to provide the data sample, for example in `with as` table consisted of `union all` of selects from `dual`?
Also, have you tried to run both selects (the one inside the `with as` and the other with it inside the `select`). Do they get you the same results inside and outside of the procedure or are you able to pinpoint the difference?

Comment: @Aleksander that format may work, but you're being very lucky. I really don't understand why anyone would not be as explicit as possible when converting strings into dates - if you leave it up to Oracle to guess what you mean, you leave your code wide open to bugs. By being exact and explicit, you remove that possibility. If your number is in `YYYYMMDD` format, why not use that format in the `to_date()`?